# Django 1.9 - Update or create, return added/edited id

Tags: python, django

I'm using update or create for a model as per the below:

```
device_inv = Inventory.objects.update_or_create(
    defaults={
            'location' : site,
            'device' : dev_name
        },
    device = dev_name
)
```

Post which I assumed I would be able to use device_inv.id. However printi device_inv I get an object and False, which I presume is the object and the answer of whether it was updated or created? (true being created, false being edited)

```
>>> print device_inv
(<Inventory: Inventory object>, False)
```

I've also tried a few ways of trying to access the object, but none seem to be working.

```
>>> for i in device_inv[0]:
...  print i
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Inventory' object is not iterable
>>> print device_inv[0]["id"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`id` is an attribute of the object instance:

```
device_inv[0].id
```

or you can just do:

```
device_inv, created = Inventory.objects.update_or_create(...)
print device_inv.id
```

Comment: that got it, i was nearly there with the ["id"]